# How to invoke a PHP closure which is assigned to a class variable?

Tags: php, class, closures

When a PHP closure is assigned to a static class variable, then later executed, such as:

```
self::$FOO = function($a) {return $a;};
self::$FOO(123)
```

PHP warns that "the function name must be a string".

If the class variable is first assigned to an ordinary variable then executed:

```
$bar = self::$FOO;
$bar(123);
```

then all is ok.

Is there a way to execute the closure using the class variable directly, without first assigning it to an ordinary variable?

Comment: Why don't you use a static function instead?

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: My PHP version is 5.3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`__invoke()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) to call a closure with the `$foo()` syntax.

A simple example:

```
class MyClass {
  public static $closure;

  function myFunction() {
    self::$closure = function($a) { echo $a; };
    self::$closure->__invoke(123);
  }
}

$class = new MyClass;
$class->myFunction();
```

This will print out `123` :)